# How to delay running playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which creates a virtual machine in vCenter. During creation the VM mounts iso image and installs OS automatically. After installation VM gets its IP address. I want to continue running playbook, but using the IP.

I read about `wait_for`, but I don't understand how to use it. Or maybe there is another way do it?

Playbook below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  user: ansible
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - ../roles/vm-create/vars/default.yml
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "name_VM"
      prompt: "VM name:"
      private: no
      default: "vm001"

    - name: "vcenter_user"
      prompt: "vCenter user"
      private: no
      default: "root"

    - name: "vcenter_pass"
      prompt: "Enter password vCenter"
      private: yes

  roles:
    - vm-create

# waiting for the installation and gets ip (Do-Until Loops or wait_for)

- name: setting VM
  become: true
  hosts: '{{ get_ip }}'
  roles:
    - { role: ldap-client, tags: [ 'ldap' ] }
```

Comment: @techraf, sry, my english very bad. I wanted to show where you want to add

Comment: @Wtower, hm...it working before { waiting for the installation and gets up }. I try write continued. I edit, hope so understandable

Comment: @techraf  I edit, hope so understandable

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you assign the `get_ip` variable, so I assume you can reference it. It's not straightforward, because you would have to either access it with `hostvars['localhost']['get_ip`]` or you should create a dynamic inventory.

Then you just need to use a very basic `wait_for` task, but because you want to assign a role to the machine, you need to define the task in the `pre_tasks` section.

Your second play should be:

```
- name: setting VM
  become: true
  hosts: '{{ get_ip }}'
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Ensure machine at {{ get_ip }} SSH port is listening
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ get_ip }}"
        port: 22                # SSH port
        delay: 60               # wait 1 minute before trying
  roles:
    - { role: ldap-client, tags: [ 'ldap' ] }
```

Comment: I don't know how to assign. I know how to get info with help vmware_guest_facts: yes. But thanks for idea